# Get url query string with the /r/n values in it

Tags: javascript, php, query-string, icalendar

I have this query string and I want the values as it is without escaping /r/n characters but it is escaping those characters.

`ics_link=data:text/calendar;charset=utf8,BEGIN:VCALENDAR%0D%0AVERSION:2.0%0D%0ABEGIN:VEVENT%0D%0AUID:4df97e535f751923b70c0bb2c8d7f4d2%0D%0ASUMMARY:Webinar - Crystal Eye Essentials Training Module 1: Introduction to New Partners%0D%0ADTSTART;TZID=UTC:20190710T150000%0D%0ADTEND;TZID=UTC:20190710T163000%0D%0ADESCRIPTION:Webinar - Crystal Eye Essentials Training Module 1: Introduction to New Partners%0D%0ALOCATION:Online%0D%0AEND:VEVENT%0D%0AEND:VCALENDAR`

But it is saving them like this in the file without any new line character and is causing an error while importing ics file in calendar.

`BEGIN:VCALENDARVERSION:2.0BEGIN:VEVENTUID:4df97e535f751923b70c0bb2c8d7f4d2SUMMARY:Webinar - Crystal Eye Essentials Training Module 1: Introduction to New PartnersDTSTART;TZID=UTC:20190710T150000DTEND;TZID=UTC:20190710T163000DESCRIPTION:Webinar - Crystal Eye Essentials Training Module 1: Introduction to New PartnersLOCATION:OnlineEND:VEVENTEND:VCALENDAR`

This is the code I am using in PHP (Drupal):

```
$ics_download = $_GET['ics_link'];

$download_ics = "<a id='download_ics_rp' data-href='$ics_download' class='btn btn-default btn-lg' value='Download ICS' download>Download ICS</a>";
$element = array(
  '#markup' => $download_ics,
);
return $element;
```

and then getting value of data-href in javascript as follows:

```
 jQuery('#download_ics_rp').click(function(e) {
      var ics_data = jQuery(this).attr('data-href');

      var win = window.open(ics_data, '_blank');
 });
```

Comment: json_encode them

Comment: @mplungjan you mean json_encode the whole ics_link or individual parameters of ics_link?

Comment: The link - it can be decoded

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$element = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => urldecode($download_ics),
);
```

Comment: The issue is I am not getting those characters when I am getting this value from my url. I am getting string without special characters which when used shows all text in a single line without linebreaks and hence causing an error during ICS file import.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ics_download = $_GET['ics_link'];
$ics_download =  str_replace(PHP_EOL, '%0D%0A', $ics_download);
$download_ics = "<a id='download_ics_rp' data-href='$ics_download' class='btn btn-default btn-lg' value='Download ICS' download>Download ICS</a>";
$element = array(
  '#markup' => $download_ics,
);
return $element;
```